# Why $card N < Card P(N)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\Bbb N (0), \Bbb N(1), \Bbb N(2), ...$ is subset of $P(N)$.

$\Bbb N(0)=$ empty set

$N(1)=\{\{1\}, \{2\}, ...\}$

$f: \Bbb N→\Bbb N$, $f(x)=\{x\}$ so $\Bbb N(1)=f(\Bbb N)$

$\Bbb N(2)=\{\{1, 1\}, \{1, 2\}, ... \{2, 1\}, ...\}$

$g : \Bbb N×\Bbb N→\Bbb N×\Bbb N$, $g(x\in \Bbb N, y\in \Bbb N)=\{x, y\}$ $g$ is a bijection.

$\Bbb N(2)$ is subset of $g(\Bbb N, \Bbb N)$, and $g(\Bbb N, \Bbb N)$~$\Bbb N×\Bbb N$~$\Bbb N$

$\Bbb N(2)$ is countable infinite.

$\Bbb N(3), \Bbb N(4), ...$ all set is countable infinite, conclusion is $P(\Bbb N)$~$\Bbb N$

but according to Cantor's theorem, card $A$ < card $P(A)$ is true.
Seek help in what is wrong with the above expression.

Comment: $\{x,y\}$ is not an element of $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$.

Comment: Also, $\{2,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ in your $N(2)$ should be the same thing.

Comment: @Gae.S. There are certainly errors here, but if he defines $g : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \{X \in P(\mathbb{N}) : |X| \leq 2\}$ then it gives a surjection as defined, so that error can at least be patched.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I agree that if I were to write both proofs I'd do it well and the visual rendering would be similar to the current version, if read by a person who is unfamiliar with elementary nuances of set theory.

Comment: The missing step between "N(0), N(1), N(2), ... are all countably infinite" and "P(N) is countably infinite" is the assertion that the union of all these sets is P(N), which is false. For example, P(N) contains the set {1, 3, 5, 7, ...} which is not in any of the N(0), N(1), N(2), ...

Comment: P.S. I rolled back @Fareed's edit since it broke a lot of the content, e.g. "P(N)~N" became $P(N)~N$ which is meaningless.

Comment: {x, y} is my mistake. but assume this set x∈N, y∈N {x, y}∈N(2). then N(2)⊆g(N, N), and g(N, N)~N. card N(2)≤ card N, so N(2)~N

Answer (score 1):

You are only considering the *finite* subsets. There are indeed only countably many of those. (I think there are some errors in your reasoning, but it basically works out like what you have in mind.) However, when you include all of the infinite subsets (e.g. the whole set, or the even numbers) as well, it becomes uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly concluded that the subset $$\{X \in P(\mathbb{N}) : |X| < \infty\}$$ is countable.  However, there are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ which have an infinite cardinality you haven't included.

Comment: I wouldn't say that he concluded it correctly. I'd call it a lucky guess.

Comment: @Gae.S. Without knowing who I'm talking to, I tend to default to "optimistic lecturer"... I had too many students break down in tears for my simply stating they're wrong in my short stint teaching college freshmen/sophomores.

Comment: Fair enough.${}$

Comment: Can you please adda proofon why the infinite subsets of $\Bbb N$ are uncountable?

Comment: @FareedAF Cantor's diagonal argument shows that $P(\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable so $$P(\mathbb{N}) = \{X \in P(\mathbb{N}) : |X| < \infty\} \cup \{X \in P(\mathbb{N}) : |X| = \infty\}$$ cannot be the union of two countable sets.

Comment: thanks. your mean is X=Union N(0), N(1), N(2), ... X is subset of P(N) and IXI<∞?